# Sigma sign problem from Spivak's calculus text ch 2-2

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I need to find a formula for $$ \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = 1^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (2n-1)^2 $$ This problem is contained in Spivak's calculus ch2-2. I know that:  $$ \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $$ and $$ \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$ and I can use both these formulas.

Here is what I did:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n (4i^2 - 4i + 1) = 4\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 - 4 \sum_{i=1}^n i + n $$
$$ \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = 4 \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - 4 \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n $$

Is that correct? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check is to take the (known) sum of the squares up to $2n$, then subtract $4$ times the sum of the squares up to halfway, because this removes the even squares:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2 -\sum_{k=1}^n (2k)^2 = \frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6} - 4\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{1}{3}n(2n+1)(4n+1-2(n+1)) = \frac{1}{3}n(2n+1)(2n-1) $$

Answer (score 3):

Note that 
$$k^2=\binom k2+\binom {k+1}2$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-1)^2&=\sum_{i=1}^n {2i-1\choose 2}+{2i\choose 2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\binom i2\\
&={2n+1\choose 3}\qquad\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

NB - It is interesting to note that
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^n(2i-1)^2&&=1^2+3^3+5^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2&&={2n+1\choose 3}\quad\text {as shown above, and}\\
&\sum_{i=1}^n (2i)^2&&=2^2+4^2+6^2+\cdots+(2n)^2&&={2n+2\choose 3}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: nice solution! I must say (+1)

Comment: @hxthanh - Thanks! Very kind of you.