# Time complexity of variation on Coupon's collector problem

Tags: computational-complexity, coupon-collector

I need to know the complexity of the following algorithm:

Draw a set of `n` numbers from a larger set of `m` numbers, one by one, randomly, with replacement. The result may be any set of numbers as long as the size is `n` and the elements are different.

This is a variation of the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem): we do not have to draw all `m` elements, any set of different numbers of size `n` will do.

Example:

`n = 3`, `m = 5`, `result = {1,5,2}` produced by successive draws `1,1,5,1,5,2` from `pool {1,2,3,4,5}`

What is the average time complexity of this problem?

Comment: use hash sets - average O(n)

Comment: @kotomord I updated my question. The implementation must draw one by one randomly.

Comment: Are "average time complexity" and "time complexity of variation" supposed to be the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected 
number of trials until your collection has $n$ distinct elements is:
$${m\over m}+{m\over m-1}+{m\over m-2}+\cdots +{m\over m-n+1}. $$

Comment: I have difficulty seeing how this would produce $m\log m$ when $n=m.$

Comment: @MarkoRiedel When $n=m$, this is $m H_m$.

Comment: I get from your formula for $m=n$ $$\sum_{p=0}^{m-1} \frac{m-p}{m} = \frac{1}{2} (m+1).$$

Comment: Let $m = 5$, $n = 2$, so we get $m - n + 1 = 4$, $\sum_{i = 4}^{5} \frac{i}{m} = \frac{4}{5} + \frac{5}{5} = 1.8$, but it should be at least $2$. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel Quite right, I had the fractions in my formula upside down. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MichielBorkent Glad to help. This formula is derived in the same way as the full formula in the Wikipedia entry for the "coupon collector problem".

Comment: @Byron How I understand it informally: The expected amount of  draws the first time is always $1$. The second time the chance on a correct draw is $(m - 1)/m$, so the expected amount of draws becomes $m/(m-1)$. Repeat until we have $n$ elements.

Comment: @MichielBorkent Exactly correct!

Answer (score 7):

By way of enrichment here  is the complexity using Stirling numbers
of   the   second   kind.   Using   the  notation   from   this   [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609459/)  we  have  $n$
coupons, and ask  about the expected time until  a multiset containing
instances of $j$ different coupons has been drawn.

First let  us verify  that we indeed  have a  probability distribution
here. We have for the number $T$ of coupons being $m$ draws that

$$P[T=m] = \frac{1}{n^m} \times 
{n\choose j-1} \times {m-1\brace j-1} \times (j-1)!
\times (n+1-j).$$

What  happens here  is that  for a  run of  $m$ samples  to  produce a
multiset containing  instances of $j$ different coupons  for the first
time on  the last sample we have  two parts, a prefix  of length $m-1$
and a terminal sample that completes the set. Therefore we must choose
the $j-1$  values excluding  the one that  occurs last for  the prefix
from the $n$ possibilities which gives the first binomial coefficient.
Next we partition  the first $m-1$ slots into  $j-1$ non-empty sets in
an  ordered  set partition.   (Stirling  number  and factorial).   The
smallest value chosen gets the slots listed in the first set, the next
one  those  in   the  second  set  etc.   Finally   we  get  $n-(j-1)$
possibilities ($j-1$  values from the  prefix have already  been used)
for the  terminal sample that  completes the selection.   Combine with
$n^m$ possible choices.

Recall the OGF  of the Stirling numbers of the  second kind which says
that

$${n\brace k} = [z^n] \prod_{q=1}^k \frac{z}{1-qz}.$$

This gives for the sum of the probabilities

$$\sum_{m\ge 1} P[T=m]
= {n\choose j-1} (j-1)! (n+1-j) 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{m-1}} {m-1\brace j-1}.$$

Focusing on the sum we obtain

$$\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{m-1}}
[z^{m-1}] \prod_{q=1}^{j-1} \frac{z}{1-qz}
= \prod_{q=1}^{j-1} \frac{1/n}{1-q/n}
\\ = \prod_{q=1}^{j-1} \frac{1}{n-q}
= \frac{(n-j)!}{(n-1)!}.$$

Combining this with the outer factor we get

$${n\choose j-1} (j-1)! (n+1-j) 
\frac{1}{n} \frac{(n-j)!}{(n-1)!}
\\ = {n\choose j-1} (j-1)! \frac{(n+1-j)!}{n!} = 1$$

This confirms it being a probability distribution.

We then get for the expectation that

$$\sum_{m\ge 1} m\times P[T=m]
\\ = {n\choose j-1} (j-1)! (n+1-j) 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{m}{n^{m-1}} {m-1\brace j-1}.$$

We once more focus on the sum to get

$$\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{m}{n^{m-1}}
[z^{m-1}] \prod_{q=1}^{j-1} \frac{z}{1-qz}
= \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{m}{n^{m-1}}
[z^{m}] z \prod_{q=1}^{j-1} \frac{z}{1-qz}
\\ = \left.\left( \prod_{q=0}^{j-1} 
\frac{z}{1-qz} \right)'\right|_{z=1/n}
\\ = \left.\left( \prod_{q=0}^{j-1} 
\frac{z}{1-qz} \sum_{p=0}^{j-1} \frac{1-pz}{z}
\frac{1}{(1-pz)^2}
\right)\right|_{z=1/n}
\\ = \left.\left( \prod_{q=0}^{j-1} 
\frac{z}{1-qz} \sum_{p=0}^{j-1} \frac{1}{z}
\frac{1}{1-pz}
\right)\right|_{z=1/n}
\\ = \prod_{q=0}^{j-1} \frac{1/n}{1-q/n} 
\sum_{p=0}^{j-1} \frac{1}{1/n}
\frac{1}{1-p/n}
\\ = \prod_{q=0}^{j-1} \frac{1}{n-q} 
\sum_{p=0}^{j-1}
\frac{n^2}{n-p}
= n \prod_{q=1}^{j-1} \frac{1}{n-q} 
\sum_{p=0}^{j-1}
\frac{1}{n-p}.$$

Retrieving the outer factor we have

$${n\choose j-1} (j-1)! (n+1-j) 
\frac{1}{n} \frac{(n-j)!}{(n-1)!} \times n 
\sum_{p=0}^{j-1} \frac{1}{n-p}.$$

The front simplifies to one as before and we are left with

$$n\sum_{p=0}^{j-1} \frac{1}{n-p}
= n \left(\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-p}
- \sum_{p=j}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-p}\right).$$

This is
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\Large
 n \times \left( H_n - H_{n-j} \right)}$$

This yields  $n H_n$ when $j  = n$ and  $1$ when $j=1$ which  are both
correct. Using  $H_n \sim \log n  + \gamma$ we  get for $j =  n/2$ the
expectation $n\log 2.$

Comment: Thanks for your post. It's a bit hard for me to follow, since I'm not using this kind of math every day, but I'll do my best to understand. You end up with $n×(H_n−H_{n−j})$. Why is $m$ not present in this expression anymore? How do I calculate the expected amount of draws in terms of $n$ and $m$ now?

Comment: I apologize -- I tried to match the notation from the linked to article. In the above post we have $n$ as the total number of available types and $j$ as the size of the set we are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the same outcome as Byron. How I understand it informally: The expected amount of  draws the first time is always $1$. The second time the chance on a correct draw is $(n - 1)/n$, so the expected amount of draws becomes $n/(n-1)$. Repeat until we have $j$ elements.