# Coupon Collector Problem with multiple copies and X amount of coupons already collected

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

I have a variant of the coupon collector problem where there are $n$ different coupons being collected, which are being drawn with equal probability and with replacement, but 2 copies of each coupon is needed.  Now say I have a total of $X$ number of relevant coupons collected of the $2n$ total number of coupons for a full set, and want to know how many extra unneeded coupons you should have.  What would be an equation for that?
I have found on Wikipedia an equation for the number of draws needed to get a full set of one of each coupon, and number of draws needed to get a full set of multiple copies of each coupon.

$E(T) = n\log{n} + γn + {\frac{1}{2}} + O({\frac{1}{n}})$, where $\gamma \approx 0.5772156649$

$E(Tm) = n\log{n} + (m-1)n\log\log{n} + O(n)$, as $n→∞$

Where $m$ is the number of copies of each coupon to be collected, so 2 in this case, and $Tm$ is the first time $m$ copies of each coupon are collected.

I also found this from a previous question.  [Coupon Collector's Problem with X amount of coupons already collected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315285/coupon-collectors-problem-with-x-amount-of-coupons-already-collected/2315295#2315295)

> The probability $p_i$ of selecting a new coupon thus equals $\frac{n-i+1}{n}$, and the expected number of draws needed to draw a new coupon equals $\frac{1}{p_i} = \frac{n}{n-i+1}$. As such, the expected value for the time needed to draw all $n$ coupons can be calculated as:
>
> $$E[T] = \frac{n}{n} + \frac{n}{n-1} + \ldots + \frac{n}{1} = n \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}$$
>
> In this case, however, we have already drawn $X$ unique coupons. As such, the estimated number of draws needed to find all $n$ coupons equals:
>
> $$E[T] = E[t_{X+1}] + E[t_{X+2}] + \ldots + E[t_n] = n \sum_{k=1}^{n-X} \frac{1}{k}$$

So to find the total number of drawn coupons upon collecting the $X^{th}$ unique coupon, the equation would be
$$n \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}-n \sum_{k=1}^{n-X} \frac{1}{k} $$

The total number of just unneeded duplicate coupons would be
$$n \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}- n \sum_{k=1}^{n-X} \frac{1}{k} - X $$

I'm not sure how to combine these two equations, $E(Tm) = n\log{n} + (m-1)n\log\log{n} + O(n)$, as $n→∞$ and $n \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}}-n \sum_{k=1}^{n-X} \frac{1}{k}$, to get the total number of coupons drawn upon having X number of relevant coupons collected towards a full collection of 2 of each coupon. Then with that equation just subtract X (the number of relevant coupons collected) from the total number to get the total unneeded coupons. I will admit I’m not in a math profession or have done any higher level math lately, but if I understand correctly the first equation is more of an approximation of the value, while the second equation is more exact. So I'm not sure how to combine them or if they can be easily combined.

Also I somewhat understand $O(n)$ and its use, I’m not sure how to input it with the rest of the equation into wolframalpha or even excel, the end goal of where I want to us this equation.  The maximum number of coupons would be about 100 if that helps.  If it would be easier it, the total number of coupons that have only 1 copy and number of coupons that have 2 copies collected could be used as an input instead of the total number of relevant coupons collected.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a computational  contribution where we derive a closed
form (as  opposed to  an infinite  series) of  the expected  number of
draws required to see all coupons at least twice when a number $n'$ of
coupons from the $n$ types where  $n' < n$ have already been collected
in  two instances.   We then  observe  that the  expectation does  not
simplify.   It  seems  like  a  rewarding  challenge  to  compute  the
asymptotics  for these  expectations using  probabilistic methods  and
compare them to the closed form presented below.

Using      the       notation      from       this      [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426510/) we  have from
first principles that

$$P[T = m] = \frac{1}{n^m}\times {n-n'\choose 1}\times
(m-1)! [z^{m-1}] \exp(n'z)
\left(\exp(z) - 1 - z\right)^{n-n'-1}
\frac{z}{1}.$$

We **verify that this is  a probability distribution**. We get

$$\sum_{m\ge 2} P[T=m]
\\ = (n-n') \sum_{m\ge 2} \frac{1}{n^m}
(m-1)! [z^{m-2}] \exp(n'z)
\left(\exp(z) - 1 - z\right)^{n-n'-1}
\\ = (n-n') \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^m}
(m+1)! [z^{m}] \exp(n'z)
\left(\exp(z) - 1 - z\right)^{n-n'-1}
\\ = (n-n') \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^m}
(m+1)! [z^{m}] \exp(n'z)
\\ \times \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} \exp((n-n'-1-p)z) 
(-1)^{p} (1+z)^p
\\ = (n-n') \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^m}
(m+1)!
\\ \times  [z^{m}]
\sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} \exp((n-1-p)z) 
(-1)^{p} (1+z)^p
\\ = (n-n') \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^m}
(m+1)!
\\ \times 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} 
\sum_{q=0}^{m} 
[z^{m-q}] \exp((n-1-p)z) 
(-1)^{p} [z^q] (1+z)^p
\\ = (n-n') \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^m}
(m+1)!
\\ \times 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} 
\sum_{q=0}^{m} 
\frac{(n-1-p)^{m-q}}{(m-q)!}
(-1)^{p} {p\choose q}.$$

Re-arranging the order of the sums now yields

$$(n-n') \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} 
\\ \times \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^m} (m+1)!
\sum_{q=0}^{m} 
\frac{(n-1-p)^{m-q}}{(m-q)!}
(-1)^{p} {p\choose q}
\\ = (n-n') \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} 
\\ \times 
\sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^{p} {p\choose q}
\sum_{m\ge q} \frac{1}{n^m} (m+1)! 
\frac{(n-1-p)^{m-q}}{(m-q)!}.$$

Simplifying the inner sum we get

$$\frac{1}{n^q} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^m} (m+q+1)! 
\frac{(n-1-p)^{m}}{m!}
\\ = \frac{(q+1)!}{n^q} \sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{n^m} 
{m+q+1\choose q+1} (n-1-p)^m
\\ = \frac{(q+1)!}{n^q} \frac{1}{(1-(n-1-p)/n)^{q+2}}
= (q+1)! n^2 \frac{1}{(p+1)^{q+2}}.$$

We thus obtain for the sum of the probabilities

$$\sum_{m\ge 2} P[T=m] =
(n-n') \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p}   (-1)^{p}
\sum_{q=0}^p {p\choose q}
(q+1)! \frac{1}{(p+1)^{q+2}}.$$

Repeat to instantly obtain for **the expectation**

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
E[T] = n (n-n') \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} (-1)^{p}
\sum_{q=0}^p {p\choose q}
\frac{(q+2)!}{(p+1)^{q+3}}.}$$

Now to simplify these we start with the inner sum from the probablity
using the fact that

$$\sum_{q=0}^p {p\choose q} (q+1)! \frac{1}{(p+1)^{q+1}} = 1$$

which was proved by residues at the cited link from the introduction.
We then obtain

$$(n-n') \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} 
\frac{(-1)^{p}}{p+1}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'\choose p+1} (-1)^p
=  - \sum_{p=1}^{n-n'} {n-n'\choose p} (-1)^p
\\ = 1 - \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'} {n-n'\choose p} (-1)^p
= 1 - (1-1)^{n-n'} = 1$$

which  confirms it  being  a probability  distribution.   We will  not
attempt  this   manipulation  with   the  expectation,   since  actual
computation  of the  values indicates  that  it does  not simplify  as
announced earlier.  For example,  these are  the expectations  for the
pairs $(2n', n'):$

$$4,11,{\frac {347}{18}},{\frac {12259}{432}},
{\frac {41129339}{1080000}},{\frac {390968681}{8100000}},
{\frac {336486120012803}{5717741400000}}, \ldots$$

and for pairs $(3n', n'):$

$${\frac {33}{4}},{\frac {12259}{576}},{\frac {390968681}{10800000}},
{\frac {2859481756726972261}{54646360473600000}}, \ldots$$

The reader who seeks numerical  evidence confirming the closed form or
additional clarification  of the problem  definition used is  asked to
consult  the  following simple  C  program  whose output  matched  the
formula on all cases that were examined.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int n = 6 , np = 3, j = 3, trials = 1000; 

  if(argc >= 2){
    n = atoi(argv[1]);
  }

  if(argc >= 3){
    np = atoi(argv[2]);
  }

  if(argc >= 4){
    j = atoi(argv[3]);
  }

  if(argc >= 5){
    trials = atoi(argv[4]);
  }

  assert(1 <= n);
  assert(1 <= np && np < n);  
  assert(1 <= j);
  assert(1 <= trials);

  srand48(time(NULL));
  long long data = 0;

  for(int tind = 0; tind < trials; tind++){
    int seen = np; int steps = 0; 
    int dist[n];

    for(int cind = 0; cind < n; cind++){
      if(cind < np) 
        dist[cind] = j;
      else
        dist[cind] = 0;
    }

    while(seen < n){
      int coupon = drand48() * (double)n;

      steps++;

      if(dist[coupon] == j-1)
        seen++;
      dist[coupon]++;
    }

    data += steps;
  }

  long double expt = (long double)data/(long double)trials;
  printf("[n = %d, np = %d, j = %d, trials = %d]: %Le\n", 
         n, np, j, trials, expt);

  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all this work. I'm still a bit confused though.  For the equation ${ E[T] = n (n-n') \sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose p} (-1)^{p} \sum_{q=0}^p {p\choose q} \frac{(q+2)!}{(p+1)^{q+3}}.}$ there are only 2 variable to input, n and n', right? The total number of unique coupons in the set (n) and the total number of coupons selected twice (n'). When I try to solve it I'm left with p's and q's and not an actual number.  I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what because it all seems to be entered into wolframalpha correctly.

Comment: Like if n=50 and n'=44, I get $75 (-1)^p  2^{p + 7} (q + 2)! (p + 1)^{-q - 3}$

Comment: Using Mathematica syntax when I enter EX [n_, np_] := 
 n*(n - np)*
  Sum[Binomial[n - np - 1, p]*(-1)^p*
    Sum[Binomial[p, q]*(q + 2)!/(p + 1)^(q + 3), {q, 0, p}], {p, 0, 
    n - np - 1}] I get for N[EX[50, 44]] the value 201.116.

Comment: The Maple syntax is EX := (n,np) -> n*(n-np)*add(binomial(n-np-1,p)*add((-1)^p*binomial(p,q)*(q+2)!*1/(p+1)^(q+3), q=0..p), p=0..n-np-1); evalf(EX(50,44)); and produces 201.1155766.