# Formula to determine how many quarters needed to buy remaining baseball cards in collection?

Tags: linear-algebra, coupon-collector

I apologize in advance if I'm not explaining this well.  I'm trying to solve a problem I'm having at work but I can't think of the mathematical formula needed in order to solve it.  Rather than bore you with technical jargon related to my job, I've changed the scenario to a baseball card collection for simplicity sake:

**Problem:** I want to determine how many US quarters I will need in order to have the highest probability of completing a unique set of baseball cards. I already have 30 of the 40 cards within the set but each card I receive is randomly selected from the 40 available in the set.

1. 1 US dollar = 4 US quarters
2. I already have 30 of the 40 cards
3. Each card costs 1 dollar (i.e. 4 quarters)
4. I want a unique set of cards BUT, each time I pay 1 dollar to receive a card, it can be any one of the 40 cards within the set

So, seeing as how I have 30 of the 40 cards of the current set, my chances of receiving card #31 is 1 in 4.  Therefore, I would need 4 dollars (or 16 quarters) to ensure the highest probability that I get a unique card #31.

Card #32 however, the odds would be 9/40.  Card #33, the odds would be 8/40, or 1/5.  Etc.

So, I'm just trying to write up a formula that would reflect the total number of US quarters needed to have the highest probability of completing a unique set of cards in this scenario.

Comment: Look up the coupon collector problem.  There are cases on this site or look in Wikipedia

Comment: The problem is ill-posed. The probability is higher the more cards you buy, so there's no amount that yields the highest probability. (In particular, it's not true that you "need $4$ dollars to ensure the highest probability" -- if you invest $5$ dollars, the probability is even higher.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have 30 of the 40 possible coupons already, the probability that the next coupon you buy will be a new one is $10/40$; so the expected number of coupons you must buy before getting a new one is $40/10$.

Once you have your first new coupon, the probability that your next coupon will be one you don't have is $9/40$, so the expected number of coupons you must buy to get a second new coupon is $40/9$.

Continuing in this way, we see that the expected number of coupons you must buy in order to get one you don't already have is $40/10, 40/9, 40/8, \dots , 40/1$.
So in all, you can expect to buy 
$$\frac{40}{10} + \frac{40}{9} +\frac{40}{8} +\dots +\frac{40}{1} = 40 \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{10} \right) = 117.1587302
$$
coupons in order to complete the set.

Answer (score 3):

The       post       at       the      following       [MSE       link
2720594](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720594/) treats the
same problem using  $n$ coupons where $n'$ have already  been seen and
coupons  have to  be collected  in  two instances.   With the  present
scenario we only have to see them once.

Using     the     notation     from     this     [MSE     link
2426510](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2426510/)   we  have
from first principles that

$$\mathrm{P}[T = m] = \frac{1}{n^m}\times {n-n'\choose 1}\times
(m-1)! [z^{m-1}] \exp(n'z)
\left(\exp(z) - 1\right)^{n-n'-1}.$$

We shall see that with this  closed form for the probabilities, we can
not only compute the expectation of the number of draws to collect the
remaining coupons but also the second factorial moment if desired, and
the  variance.  To  start **verify  that this  is a
probability distribution**. We get

$$(n-n') \sum_{m\ge n-n'} \frac{1}{n^m}\times
(m-1)! [z^{m-1}] \exp(n'z)
\left(\exp(z) - 1\right)^{n-n'-1}
\\ = (n-n') \sum_{m\ge n-n'} \frac{1}{n^m}
(m-1)! [z^{m-1}] \exp(n'z)
\\ \times 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-1-q} \exp(qz)
\\ = (n-n') \sum_{m\ge n-n'} \frac{1}{n^m}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-1-q} 
(n'+q)^{m-1}
\\ = \frac{n-n'}{n} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-1-q} 
\sum_{m\ge n-n'} \frac{1}{n^{m-1}} (n'+q)^{m-1}
\\ = \frac{n-n'}{n} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-1-q} 
\frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}/n^{n-n'-1}}
{1-(n'+q)/n}
\\ = \frac{n-n'}{n^{n-n'-1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'-1\choose n-n'-1-q} (-1)^{n-n'-1-q} 
\frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}}{n-n'-q}
\\ = \frac{1}{n^{n-n'-1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'\choose n-n'-q} (-1)^{n-n'-1-q} 
(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}
\\ = - \frac{1}{n^{n-n'-1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-q} 
(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}
\\ = 1 - \frac{1}{n^{n-n'-1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'} {n-n'\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-q} 
(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}
\\ = 1 - (n-n'-1)! [z^{n-n'-1}] \frac{\exp(n'z)}{n^{n-n'-1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'} {n-n'\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-q} \exp(qz)
\\ = 1 - (n-n'-1)! [z^{n-n'-1}] \frac{\exp(n'z)}{n^{n-n'-1}} 
(\exp(z)-1)^{n-n'}.$$

Note however that $\exp(z)-1=z+\cdots$ and hence $(\exp(z)-1)^{n-n'} =
z^{n-n'}+\cdots$ which means  the coefficient extractor $[z^{n-n'-1}]$
is zero and we are left with just the first term, which is one, and we
indeed have a probability distribution.

**Continuing with the expectation** we evidently require

$$\sum_{m\ge n-n'} \frac{m}{n^{m-1}} (n'+q)^{m-1}
\\ = \frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}}{n^{n-n'-1}}
\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{m+n-n'-1}{n^{m-1}} (n'+q)^{m-1}.$$

The simple component from this is

$$(n-n'-1) \frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}}{n^{n-n'-1}}
\frac{1}{1-(n'+q)/n}.$$

Here we recognize a term that we have already evaluated which yields
on substitution into the outer sum the value $n-n'-1.$ Evaluating
the second term we get for the expectation

$$n-n'-1 
- \frac{1}{n^{n-n'-1}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-q}
\frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}}{1-(n'+q)/n}$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[T] = n-n'-1 
- \frac{1}{n^{n-n'-2}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-q}
\frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}}{n-n'-q}.}$$

Introducing

$$f(z) = \frac{(n-n')!}{n-n'-z} (n'+z)^{n-n'-1}
\prod_{p=0}^{n-n'} \frac{1}{z-p}$$

we observe that for $0\le q\le n-n'-1$

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=q} f(z) 
= \frac{(n-n')!}{n-n'-q} (n'+q)^{n-n'-1}
\prod_{p=0}^{q-1} \frac{1}{q-p}
\prod_{p=q+1}^{n-n'} \frac{1}{q-p}
\\ = \frac{(n-n')!}{n-n'-q} (n'+q)^{n-n'-1}
\frac{1}{q!} \frac{(-1)^{n-n'-q}}{(n-n'-q)!}$$

so that the expectation becomes

$$n-n'-1 - \frac{1}{n^{n-n'-2}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} \mathrm{Res}_{z=q} f(z).$$

Now residues sum to  zero and the residue at infinity  is zero as well
since $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} 2\pi R \times R^{n-n'-1}/R/R^{n-n'+1}
= 0.$ So the sum is minus the residue at $z=n-n':$

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=n-n'} \frac{(n-n')!}{z-(n-n')} (n'+z)^{n-n'-1}
\prod_{p=0}^{n-n'} \frac{1}{z-p}.$$

This needs

$$(n-n')! \left. \left( (n'+z)^{n-n'-1}
\prod_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} \frac{1}{z-p}
\right)' \right|_{z=n-n'}$$

Note that  when we are waiting  for one last coupon  i.e. $n=n'+1$ the
sum formula yields for  the expectation $0 - n \times (-1)  = n$ so we
may suppose that $n\gt n'+1.$ Continue with the derivative to get

$$(n-n')! \left. (n-n'-1)  (n'+z)^{n-n'-2}
\prod_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} \frac{1}{z-p} \right|_{z=n-n'}
\\- (n-n')! \left.  (n'+z)^{n-n'-1}
\prod_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} \frac{1}{z-p} 
\sum_{p=0}^{n-n'-1} \frac{1}{z-p} 
\right|_{z=n-n'}
\\ =  (n-n'-1) n^{n-n'-2} -  n^{n-n'-1} H_{n-n'}.$$

Replacing this in the main formula  yields the closed form (which also
produces the correct value for $n-n' = 1$ BTW)

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[T] = n \times  H_{n-n'} \quad \sim \quad  n \log (n-n')
+ \gamma n + \frac{1}{2} \frac{n}{n-n'}
- \frac{1}{12} \frac{n}{(n-n')^2} +\cdots.}$$

We  thus  obtain  for  forty  coupons with  thirty  already  seen  the
expectation

$$\frac{7381}{63} \approx 117.1587302.$$

**Moving on to conclude with the variance** we now work with

$$\sum_{m\ge n-n'} \frac{m^2}{n^{m-1}} (n'+q)^{m-1}
\\ = \frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}}{n^{n-n'-1}}
\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{(m+n-n'-1)^2}{n^{m-1}} (n'+q)^{m-1}.$$

Here we recognize two easy pieces which are

$$(n-n'-1)^2$$

and

$$2 (n-n'-1) (n H_{n-n'} - (n-n'-1)).$$

With $\sum_{m\ge  1} m^2  w^{m-1}  = (1+w)/(1-w)^3$  we have  two
additional sum terms:

$$- \frac{1}{n^{n-n'-3}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-q}
\frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'-1}}{(n-n'-q)^2}$$

and

$$- \frac{1}{n^{n-n'-2}} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-n'-1} {n-n'\choose q} (-1)^{n-n'-q}
\frac{(n'+q)^{n-n'}}{(n-n'-q)^2}.$$

For the first of these we use $f(z)/(n-n'-z)$ and obtain five pieces:

$$(n-n'-1)(n-n'-2) n^{n-n'-3} - 2(n-n'-1) n^{n-n'-2} H_{n-n'} 
\\ + n^{n-n'-1} H_{n-n'}^2
+ n^{n-n'-1} H^{(2)}_{n-n'}.$$

The second  sum only differs in  the exponent on $n'+q$  and we
obtain

$$(n-n')(n-n'-1) n^{n-n'-2} - 2(n-n') n^{n-n'-1} H_{n-n'} 
\\ + n^{n-n'} H_{n-n'}^2
+ n^{n-n'} H^{(2)}_{n-n'}.$$

Collecting everything including a factor of $1/2$ on the derivative we
finally have (observe cancelation of the polynomial in $n$ and $n'$)

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[T^2] = 
n^2 \times H_{n-n'}^2 
- n \times H_{n-n'} 
+ n^2 \times H_{n-n'}^{(2)}.}$$

Using that

$$\mathrm{Var}[T] = \mathrm{E}[T^2] - \mathrm{E}[T]^2$$

we get

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{Var}[T] = 
n^2 \times H_{n-n'}^{(2)} 
- n \times H_{n-n'}.}$$

The dominant term here is $\sim \frac{\pi^2}{6} n^2.$

These  results  for  the  expectation and  the  variance  are  in
agreement     with    [Wikipedia     on    the     coupon    collector
problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem),
where  they are  derived by  probabilistic methods  as opposed  to the
Stirling numbers used here.