# Singletons in coupon collecting problem

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

There are $n$ types of coupons. All types are equally likely to turn up and each "draw" of a coupon is independent of others. If someone collects coupons until they have a complete set of all the $n$ types, what is the expected value of the number of coupons that only appear once in this complete set?

In the book, they give this solution:

Let $X$ be the number of singletons. Let $T_i$ be the $i$th type of coupon collected and $A_i$ the event that there is only one $T_i$ coupon in the set. Then $$\mathbb{E} [X]=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}(A_i)$$
This much I understand. What I do not understand is the following:

Now, at the moment when the first type $T_i$ coupon is collected, there remain $n − i$
types that need to be collected to have a complete set. Because, starting at this moment,
each of these $n − i + 1$ types (the $n − i$ not yet collected and type $T_i$) is equally
likely to be the last of these types to be collected, it follows that the type $T_i$ will be the
last of these types (and so will be a singleton) with probability $\frac {1}{
n−i+1}$.

I do not understand this derivation of the probability. If $T_i$ just got collected, how is it that it can be collected last of the $n-i$ not yet collected types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are looking for the chance that you get another $T_i$.  You can collect it again until you have found all the other types you are looking for.  After you get the first $T_i$, they say make a list of the first occurrence after now of $T_i$ and all the coupons you have not found yet.  If $T_i$ is the last, you will only have one $T_i$ when you complete your set.  If it is not the last, you will have a duplicate $T_i$ when you complete your set.

As a specific example, say you have all the coupons except $a,b,c$.  Now you draw your first $a$ (this is $T_i$ in the above).  They say you should look at the order of the next draw of $a,b,c$.  There are $3!$ possible orders, of which $2$ have $a$ after the others, so you now have $\frac 23$ chance of getting a second $a$ before you finish the set and a $\frac 13$ chance you get your complete set while you have only one $a$.

Answer (score 2):

By way of enrichment here is the expectation using Stirling numbers of
the  second  kind.   In   referencing  the  notation  from  this  [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609459/)  we  have  $n$
coupons,  and ask  about  the  expected number  of  singletons once  a
complete set of $n$ different coupons has been drawn. We will be using
OGFs and EGFs of Stirling numbers and switch between them.

First let  us verify  that we indeed  have a  probability distribution
here. We have for the number $T$ of coupons being $m$ draws classified
according to the number of singletons that

$$P[T=m] = \frac{1}{n^m} \times {n\choose n-1} \\ \times
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q}
{m-1\choose q} q! {m-1-q\brace n-1-q}_{\ge 2}
(n-1-q)!.$$

What is  happening here  is that  we first choose  the $n-1$  types of
coupons that go into the prefix,  where the one not selected goes into
the suffix, completing the set  of coupons. Next we choose $q$ coupons
from the  ones in the prefix  which will be  represented by singletons
(factor  ${n-1\choose q}$).  Next  we choose  the  positions from  the
available  slots   where  the   singletons  will  be   placed  (factor
${m-1\choose q} q!$). We split the leftover $m-1-q$ slots into sets of
at least two elements, one for each of the $n-1-q$ types that have not
been instantiated (factor ${m-1-q\brace n-1-q}_{\ge 2} (n-1-q)!$).

This probability simplifies to

$$P[T=m] = \frac{n \times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{q!}
\frac{1}{(m-1-q)!}  {m-1-q\brace n-1-q}_{\ge 2}
\\ = \frac{n \times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} \frac{(n-1)!}{q!}
[z^{m-1-q}] \frac{(\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-1-q}}{(n-1-q)!}
\\ = \frac{n \times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q}
[z^{m-1-q}] (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-1-q}
\\ = \frac{n \times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {n-1\choose q}
[z^{m-1}] z^q (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-1-q}
\\ = \frac{n \times (m-1)!}{n^m} [z^{m-1}]
(\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}
\\ = \frac{n! \times (m-1)!}{n^m} [z^{m-1}]
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$

We then get for the sum of the probabilities (observe that the EGF has
morphed into an OGF)

$$\sum_{m\ge 1} P[T=m]
= \frac{n!}{n} \sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^{m-1}}
[z^{m-1}] \prod_{q=1}^{n-1} \frac{z}{1-qz}
= \frac{n!}{n} \prod_{q=1}^{n-1} \frac{1/n}{1-q/n}
\\ = \frac{n!}{n} \prod_{q=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n-q}
= \frac{n!}{n} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} = 1.$$

The probabilities sum to one and the sanity check goes through.

Continuing  with the  expected number  of singletons  we get  an extra
factor $q$ which yields

$$\frac{n \times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
\sum_{q=1}^{n-1} q {n-1\choose q}
[z^{m-1}] z^q (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-1-q}
\\ = \frac{n(n-1) \times (m-1)!}{n^m} [z^{m-1}]
\sum_{q=1}^{n-1} {n-2\choose q-1}
z^q (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-1-q}
\\ = \frac{n(n-1) \times (m-1)!}{n^m}
\\ \times  [z^{m-1}] z
\sum_{q=1}^{n-1} {n-2\choose q-1}
z^{q-1} (\exp(z)-z-1)^{n-2-(q-1)}
\\ = \frac{n(n-1) \times (m-1)!}{n^m}
[z^{m-2}] (\exp(z)-1)^{n-2}
\\ = \frac{n! \times (m-1)!}{n^m}
[z^{m-2}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}.$$

Now we have

$$\sum_{m\ge 2} w^{m-2} (m-1)! [z^{m-2}] 
\sum_{q\ge 0} A_q \frac{z^q}{q!}
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 2} w^{m-2} (m-1) A_{m-2}
= \left.\left(z \sum_{q\ge 0} 
A_q z^q\right)'\right|_{z=w}.$$

Applying this to the expectation yields

$$\frac{n!}{n^2} \sum_{m\ge 2} \frac{1}{n^{m-2}}
[z^{m-2}] \left(\prod_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{z}{1-qz}\right)'
\\ = \frac{n!}{n^2} \sum_{m\ge 2} \frac{1}{n^{m-2}}
[z^{m-2}] \prod_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{z}{1-qz}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{1-qz}{z} \frac{1}{(1-qz)^2}
\\ = \frac{n!}{n^2} \sum_{m\ge 2} \frac{1}{n^{m-2}}
[z^{m-2}] \prod_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{z}{1-qz}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{1/z}{1-qz}
\\ = \frac{n!}{n^2}
\prod_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{1/n}{1-q/n}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{n}{1-q/n}
\\ = n!
\prod_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{n-q}
\sum_{q=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{n-q}.$$

This simplifies to the end result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
H_n \sim \log n + \gamma}$$

where  we  have included  an  increment  of  one that  represents  the
singleton which completed the set of coupons.

There is  also a beginning  level Perl script available  which will
confirm this formula for approximately four digits precision.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

MAIN: {
    my $n = shift || 5;
    my $trials = shift || 1000;

    my $data = 0;

    for(my $tind = 0; $tind < $trials; $tind++){
        my $seen = 0; my @dist;

        @dist[1..$n] = (0) x $n;

        while($seen < $n){
            my $coupon = 1 + int(rand($n));

            $seen++ if $dist[$coupon] == 0;
            $dist[$coupon]++;
        }

        my $single = 0;
        for(my $type = 1; $type <= $n; $type++){
            $single++ if $dist[$type] == 1;
        }

        $data += $single;
    }

    print $data/$trials;
    print "\n";

    1;
}
```

This  post  made  extensive  use  of  the  technique  of  *annihilated
coefficient extractors*  (ACE). There are  more of these at  this [MSE
link  I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184319/) and  at this
[MSE  link  II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213727/)  and
also          here         at          this          [MSE         link
III](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130883/).

**Addendum.** We can simplify the  above computation somewhat by using
the species of ordered set partitions with singletons marked. This is

$$\mathfrak{S}(\mathcal{U}\mathcal{V}\mathcal{Z}
+ \mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

and has generating function

$$G(z,u,v) = \frac{1}{1-u(\exp(z)-z+vz-1)}.$$

We are partitioning $m-1$ slots into $n-1$ sets and we extract

$$(m-1)! [z^{m-1}] [u^{n-1}] G(z,u,v) 
\\ = (m-1)! [z^{m-1}] (\exp(z)-z+vz-1)^{n-1}.$$

We  thus  obtain  a  generating function  for  the  probability  which
encapsulates  its value  but  classifies according  to  the number  of
singletons which is

$$P[T = m] = \frac{1}{n^m} \times {n\choose n-1} \times
(m-1)! [z^{m-1}] (\exp(z)-z+vz-1)^{n-1}
\\ = \frac{n!\times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
[z^{m-1}] \frac{(\exp(z)-z+vz-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$

I.e. $n^m  P[T=m]$ is  the OGF  of sequences of  draws where  the last
coupon is  obtained at  draw number $m,$  classified according  to the
number  of singletons  represented by  the exponent  on $v.$  E.g. for
four coupons and six draws we obtain

$$360v+240v^2.$$

Divide by four  to account for the choice of  the last coupon, leaving
five draws and three coupons and the term $90v+60v^2$ (the last coupon
was  a singleton  but we  did not  count it  until the  very end,  see
above).  For  one singleton choose it  in three ways and  combine with
pairs of  the remaining two types  to get $3\times {5\choose  2,2,1} =
90.$ For two  singletons choose the two types in  ${3\choose 2}$ ways,
the remaining  type gets  three slots and  we have  $3\times {5\choose
3,1,1} = 60.$

Returning to the  main thread and setting $v=1$ we  remove the marking
and obtain the probability

$$\frac{n!\times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
[z^{m-1}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

and may continue as before.

We compute the  expectation by differentating with respect  to $v$ and
setting $v=1$ and obtain

$$\left.\frac{n!\times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
[z^{m-1}] (n-1) \frac{(\exp(z)-z+vz-1)^{n-2}}{(n-1)!}
\times z\right|_{v=1}
\\ = \frac{n!\times (m-1)!}{n^m} 
[z^{m-2}]\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}.$$

We then continue once more as in the first version.

Comment: It has taken me a while to read through all of this and it is really interesting indeed, I think I will need some more time to understand it all

Answer (score 0):

Let $T_i$ be the $i$-th type collected during the process of collecting all n types. For example, $T_1$ is whichever type you get on the first selection. Let $A_i$ be the event that $T_i$ is collected precisely once in the process of collecting all types. The claim is that $$P(A_i)=\frac{1}{n-i+1},$$ or equivalently $$P(A_{n-i+1})=\frac{1}{i}.$$ It should not be surprising to find that $P(A_n)=1$, as the process stops immediately upon collecting $n$ types. Let us see why $P(A_{n-1})=1/2$.

At the moment when type $T_{n-1}$ is collected, we need to make sure that type $T_{n-1}$ is never picked up again as we collect type $T_n$. We can achieve this by selecting type $T_n$ in the next selection, which has probability $1/n$. Or, we encounter types $T_{1},\ldots, T_{n-2}$ in the next selection, and then type $T_n$. This has probability $\frac{n-2}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}$. Since we can encounter type $T_{1}\ldots, T_{n-2}$ arbitrary number of times, the probability that we collect type $T_n$ without touching type $T_{n-1}$ is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{n-2}{n})^k\cdot\frac{1}{n}=1/2.$$

One should be able to calculate other $P(A_i)$ based on this strategy. For examople, let us move to the extreme and show that $P(A_1)=\frac{1}{n}.$

For this, we need to make sure as we collect type $T_2$, no type $T_1$ is collected. Namely, a type $T_2$ follows immediately on the second selection. This has probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$. Next, from type $T_2$ to type $T_3$, we need to collect type $T_3$ without touching type $T_1$. Namely, only type $T_2$ can be collected. This amounts to probability $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{n})^k\cdot\frac{n-2}{n}=\frac{n-2}{n-1}.$$

In general, going from $T_{i-1}$ to $T_i$ where $i\geq 3$, we need to select type $T_{i}$, and no type $T_1$ is selected. This has probability
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{i-2}{n})^k\cdot\frac{n-i+1}{n}=\frac{n-i+1}{n-i+2}.$$ Note $\frac{i-2}{n}$ is the probability of selecting type $T_2,\ldots, T_{i-1}$, and $\frac{n-i+1}{n}$ is the probability to collect type $T_{i}$.

Finally, to make sure type $T_1$ is never collected in the remaining process, we simply require that type $T_1$ is never collected as we go from type $T_{i-1}$ to type $T_i$, for $i=2,\ldots n$. We calculated that the probability of such event is $\frac{n-i+1}{n-i+2}$. Since the selection is independent from the previous ones, we can multiply these together to get
$$\frac{n-1}{n}\times\frac{n-2}{n-1}\times\cdots\times \frac{1}{2}\times 1= \frac{1}{n}$$ as desired.