# Recursive coupon collector problems

Tags: combinatorics, coupon-collector

Consider the well-known coupon collector problem with $n$ potential coupons. If I collect a coupon per day, I know it will take me $n \cdot H_n$ days to finally collect all of them, where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number, and $H_n$ to collect each coupon on average. For example, if the coupons are the positive integers up to 12, one potential sequence of coupons could look like

```
r1=[5     2    12     9     3     2     1     8     5     6     7    11    11    11     3     4     2     9     3     5     8    12     8     3    10]
```

Note that for this example, it took me 25 days to collect them all, which is “kind of” close to $12 \cdot H_{12}=37$, with an average per coupon of $t_1=|r_1|/n=25/12=2.08$.

Now, once I obtain all of the coupons, then I will observe which ones I have obtained exactly once. I will eliminate this set $k_1$ of coupons, and take a look at how long it took me to collect the remaining $n-|k_1|$ coupons this time. Note that in this process I am always eliminating the last coupon to appear, but possibly more.

In the previous example, the coupons that appear once are

```
k1=[1     4     6     7    10]
```

which are the ones which I will remove. And the ones that can stay are

```
b1=[2     3     5     8     9    11    12]
```

Searching how long it took me in the initial sequence to get all the values I haven’t removed, I obtained:

```
r2=[5     2    12     9     3     2     8     5    11]
```

I would expect that this should have taken me on average $H_{n-|k_1|}$ days?  Here $|k_1|=5$ so this would be $H_7=2.59$. This is not that close to the actual time that it took me, which is $t_2=|r_2|/(n-|k_1|)=9/7=1.29$ in our example.

I will now check, in the second iteration, which are the coupons that I have collected exactly once, and remove them again from the sample. The coupons that appear only once are

```
k2=[3     8     9    11    12]
```

I remove them and obtain the shortest list that contains all elements in $[1:12]\setminus \{k_1 \cup k_2\}$. This gives me

```
r3=[5     2]
```

Again, I would expect that this should have taken me on average $H_{n-|k_1|-|k_2|}$ days?  Here $|k_1|=5$ and $|k_2|=5$, which gives $1.5$, which is also more than what it actually took me, which was only $t_3=|r_3|/(n-|k_1|-|k_2|)=2/2=1$ day on average.

In the end, I am interested in the average time it took me to take each coupon in each of the $r$ sequences, call this $T_n$. In our example, it took me 2.08 days on average to get my first coupons in $r_1$, this is multiplied by the number of elements that appeared only once in $r_1$, i.e. $|k_1|=5$. Then, it took me, on average, $1.29$ days to get each of the coupons in $r_2$, this is multiplied by $|k_2|=5$, and finally it took me an average of 1 day to collect each of the coupons in $r_3$, and this is multiplied by $k_3$. Finally, we divide all of it by $n$. In our example,

$$T_{12}=(5\cdot 2.08+5 \cdot 1.29+2\cdot 1)/12= 1.57$$

Thus, $T_n$ can be defined more generally as:

$$T_n=\left[\frac{1}{n}\right]\left[\frac{|k_1||r_1|}{n}+\frac{|k_2||r_2|}{n-|k_1|}+\frac{|k_3||r_3|}{n-|k_1|-|k_2|}+\ldots\right]$$

I am interested in the approximate expected value of $T_n$, particularly in its asymptotic behavior and upper/lower bounds.

My guess was that one could approximate $T_n$ by the recursive use of the initial approximation $H_n$, in which we fix that in each round we remove exactly one coupon. Therefore, we obtain $\frac{H_n + H_{n-1}+ \ldots}{n}$, which asymptotically converges to $H_n$. But, as I have shown before in the example, this approximation is not that good because the recursive approximation using $H_n$ starts getting worse and worse.

In simulations, I have found the following values for $T_n$:

| Vaue of n | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 2.1325 |
| 50 | 2.3378 |
| 100 | 2.4772 |
| 200 | 2.6004 |
| 500 | 2.7388 |

If it helps, note that the expected size of $k_1$ is $H_n$, see Section 4 in Myers, Amy N., and Herbert S. Wilf. "Some new aspects of the coupon collector's problem." SIAM review 48.3 (2006): 549-565.

Comment: From simulations up to $n=2^{16}$, the expected value seems to grow very slightly more than linearly; at most $n\log\log n$ and perhaps even just $n\log\log\log n$.

Comment: Thank you. I got similar results with simulations, and I know it doesn't converge to a constant. But what escapes me is to prove that the expected value must be larger than some (very small) function of \log(n).

Comment: You should include those efforts in the question.

Comment: About your edit on the expected size of $k_1$: This is also treated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2045183/singletons-in-coupon-collecting-problem). As usual, the expected size is much easier to obtain directly (as in that question) than using the full distribution (as in the paper you linked to).