# Picking a sample of N numbered balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> An urn contains $nr$ balls numbered $1,2..,n$ in such a way that $r$
>    balls bear the same number $i$ for each $i=1,2,...n$. $N$ balls are drawn at random without replacement. Find the probability that exactly $m$ of the numbers will appear in the sample.

Any hints would be great, I tried solving it, finally relented and checked the solution given in the text, I can't seem to understand the working though I get the idea that inclusion-exclusion is the key to solving the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by exactly m? Can you give an example

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question either. What is the given answer? That might help us understand better.

Comment: M of the same no.s or different no.s?

Comment: First select $m$ specific numbers out of $n$. For those $m$ numbers, take out $1$ ball from each number to ensure it will appear in the sample. Finally select $N - m$ balls in the remaining $m(r - 1)$ balls with those $m$ numbers freely to make up the $N$ sample. Can you count?

Answer (score 0):

We     use     the     notation    from     the     following     [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172876/)  where  there
are $n$  types of coupons with  $j$ instances of each  and $m$ coupons
being drawn without replacement. We  get from first principles for all
sequences of draws the mixed generating function

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^j \frac{j!}{(j-k)!} \frac{z^k}{k!} \right)^n.$$

Here we are  partitioning the draws into $n$ sets,  one for each type,
with $z^k/k!$  representing the  size of the  set and  $j!/(j-k)!$ the
weight according to probability. We get for the sum of all weights the
closed form

$$m! [z^m] 
\left(\sum_{k=0}^j \frac{j!}{(j-k)!} \frac{z^k}{k!} \right)^n
= m! [z^m] (1+z)^{nj} = m! \times {nj\choose m}.$$

Note also  that $(nj)^{\underline{m}}$  gives the denominators  of the
probabilities   while   $j^{\underline{k}}$   gives   the   numerators
corresponding to a set of size $k.$

We  are interested  in the  probability that  $q$ different  types are
seen, which gives the marked generating function

$$\left(1 + u\sum_{k=1}^j \frac{j!}{(j-k)!} 
\frac{z^k}{k!} \right)^n.$$

We thus have for the probability of $q$ different types

$$\frac{1}{m!} {nj\choose m}^{-1}
\times m! [z^m] [u^q]
\left(1 + u\sum_{k=1}^j \frac{j!}{(j-k)!} 
\frac{z^k}{k!} \right)^n
\\ = \frac{1}{m!} {nj\choose m}^{-1}
\times m! [z^m] {n\choose q}
\left(\sum_{k=1}^j \frac{j!}{(j-k)!} 
\frac{z^k}{k!} \right)^q
\\ = {nj\choose m}^{-1}
[z^m] {n\choose q}
\left(-1 + (1+z)^j\right)^q
\\ = {nj\choose m}^{-1}
[z^m] {n\choose q}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} (1+z)^{jp}.$$

We conclude that the desired probability is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{nj\choose m}^{-1}
{n\choose q}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} {jp \choose m}.}$$

Observing that

$${nj\choose m}^{-1} {jp\choose m} =
\frac{(jp)! \times (nj-m)!}{(jp-m)! \times (nj)!}$$

we get the alternate form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n\choose q}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} 
{nj\choose pj}^{-1}
{nj-m \choose pj-m}.}$$

E.g. for $15$  draws from $10$ types of coupons  with $3$ instances of
each we obtain the PGF

$${\frac {7\,{u}^{5}}{4308820}}+{\frac {945\,{u}^{6}}{861764}}
+{\frac {16191\,{u}^{7}}{430882}}
\\ +{\frac {112023\,{u}^{8}}{430882}}+{\frac {416745\,{u}^{9}}{861764}}
+{\frac {938223\,{u}^{10}}{4308820}},$$

a result that is not  accessible by enumeration, which was nonetheless
implemented as  a sanity check in  the following Maple code,  where it
was  found to  match the  two  closed forms  on the  values that  were
examined.

```
ENUM :=
proc(n, j, m)
option remember;
local src, recurse, gf;

    src := [seq(j, q=1..n)];

    gf := 0;

    recurse :=
    proc(prob, sofar, rest, drawn)
    local remain, choice, chinst;

        if drawn = m then
            gf := gf +
            prob*u^nops(convert(sofar, `multiset`));
            return;
        fi;

        remain := n*j-drawn;

        for choice to n do
            chinst := op(choice, rest);

            if chinst > 0 then
                recurse(prob*chinst/remain,
                        [op(sofar), choice],
                        subsop(choice=chinst-1, rest),
                        drawn+1);
            fi;
        od;
    end;

    recurse(1, [], src, 0);
    gf;
end;

gfA :=
proc(n, j, m)

    if m > n*j then return 0 fi;

    add(binomial(n*j,m)^(-1)*binomial(n,q)*
        add(binomial(q,p)*(-1)^(q-p)*binomial(j*p,m),
            p=0..q)*u^q, q=0..n);
end;

gfB :=
proc(n, j, m)

    if m > n*j then return 0 fi;

    add(binomial(n,q)*
        add(binomial(q,p)*(-1)^(q-p)*
            binomial(n*j, p*j)^(-1)*binomial(n*j-m,p*j-m),
            p=0..q)*u^q, q=0..n);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a solution by use of an extension of the Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion.  We will find the probability that the sample contains exactly $n-m$ different types, where we call all balls with the same number a "type".  Note that this is a revision of the original problem statement.

There are $\binom{nr}{N}$ possible samples of size $N$, all of which we assume are equally likely.  Say a sample has "Property $j$" if it includes no balls of type $j$ for $j=1,2,3,\dots ,n$, and let $S_i$ be the number of samples with $i$ of the properties (with over-counting) for $i=1,2,3,\dots ,n$.  If a sample has $m$ of the properties then there are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways to pick the missing ball types and $\binom{(n-m)r}{N}$ possible ways to pick $N$ balls from the remaining types.  So 
$$S_m = \binom{n}{m} \binom{(n-m)r}{N}$$
for $m = 1,2,3,...,n$.

Now define $e_m$ to be the number of samples with exactly $m$ of the properties.  By Theorem 2.8 in *Schaum's Outline of Theory and Problems of Combinatorics* by V.K. Balakrishnan,
$$e_m = \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} (-1)^k \binom{m+k}{m} S_{m+k}$$
so
$$e_m = \sum_{k=0}^{n-m} (-1)^k \binom{m+k}{m} \binom{n}{m+k} \binom{(n-m-k)r}{N}$$
and the probability that a sample pf size $N$ contains exactly $n-m$ different types of balls is
$$\frac{e_m}{\binom{nr}{N}}$$