# An urn contains n red balls, n white, n black. What is the probability of not getting all colors?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, binomial-coefficients

I have this problem which I have been struggling with for a while now

> An urn contains n red balls, n white balls and n black balls. You
>   draw k balls at random without replacement ($k\leqq n$). Find an
>   expression for the probability that you do not get all colors.

I tried to solve this in the following way:
I note that it should be logical to think P(not getting all colours in k draws) = P(getting exactly one color only in k draws OR get exactly two different colors only in k draws).

Therefore, I choose the events $A_1=\{$get one color k times$\}$ and $A_2=\{$get two colors k times$\}$

Therefore, we seek $P(A_1 \cup A_2)$.

Clearly, $A_1 = \frac{{n\choose k}}{3n\choose k}$ and  $A_2 = \frac{{2n\choose k}}{3n\choose k}$. And because the both events are disjoint, we simply get

$P(A_1 \cup A_2) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) = \frac{1}{3n\choose k}\big({n\choose k}+{2n\choose k}\big)$.

According to my textbook, however, the answer should be

$\frac{3}{3n\choose k}\big({2n\choose k}-{n\choose k}\big)$.

What am I doing wrong? Are the answers equivalent because of some mystical binomial-identity?

Comment: Your $A_1$ and $A_2$ sets are not disjoint. Indeed $A_1 \subset A_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us take the colors blue, red and green and let $B,R,G$ stand for the events that **no** blue, red, green balls are selected respectively.

Then you are looking for $P(B\cup R\cup G)$ and with [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and symmetry we find:$$P(B\cup R\cup G)=3P(B)-3P(B\cap R)=3\left[\frac{\binom{2n}{k}-\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{3n}{k}}\right]$$

Comment: Thanks!! Amazing how easy this solution is. I have a very hard time in how to effectively choose the most appropriate events for this kind of problems. If I had just set up the same configuration of events that you just did, I would have solved it in an instant using inclusion/exclusion.

Comment: Glad to help. Indeed an instant is enough. Choosing the right configuration is quite often a matter of intuiton and maturity. Both grow by practicizing maths and that is exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

You have to multiply by 3, because there are three ways to select the colors. Furthermore, when considering all ways to pick two colors, you also include the scenario where you select only one color. These must be subtracted, hence you get:

$$\frac{{3 \choose 2}\left({2n \choose k}-2{n \choose k}\right)+{3 \choose 1}{n \choose k}}{3n \choose k} = \frac{3({2n \choose k} - {n \choose k})}{3n \choose k}$$

Comment: Okey, thanks. The above comment states however that my $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not disjoint. How can they not be disjoint?

Comment: @tarkovsky123 When considering ${2n \choose k}$ for $A_2$, you also consider picking $k$ balls of the same color. Therefore, $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not disjoint.

Comment: $2n \choose k$ means you pick $k$ among the set containing $n$ balls of 1 color and n balls of another color. In this configuration it is possible that you actually pick $k$ balls of the same color which falls into your $n \choose k$ possibilities you already counted.

Comment: Okey that makes sense. But if I was to try and compute $P(A_1 \cup A_2) = P(A_1) + P(A_2) + P(A_1 \cap A_2)$, how would I, with my events above, compute $P(A_1 \cap A_2)$ ? I see now that its obvious they are not disjoint, but how to explicity calculate the intersection of the events?

Answer (score 2):

The     reader      may     want     to     consult      this     [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2683788/)  by   way  of
enrichment    where    a    much    more    general    question    was
answered. Substituting the parameters  from the present question value
by  value into  the  formula  that was  proved  there  yields for  the
complementary probability of seeing all  three colors the form (in the
following we have $n\ge 1$)

$${3n\choose k}^{-1} {3\choose 3}
\sum_{p=0}^3 {3\choose p} (-1)^{3-p} {pn\choose k}
\\ = {3n\choose k}^{-1}
\times
\left({3n\choose k} - 3{2n\choose k}
+ 3{n\choose k} - {0\choose k}\right).$$

This gives  for $k=0$ (no balls  drawn) the probability of  seeing all
three colors

$$1\times ( 1-3+3-1 ) = 0.$$

For $1\le k\le 3n$ we obtain

$${3n\choose k}^{-1}
\times
\left({3n\choose k} - 3{2n\choose k} + 3{n\choose k}\right).$$

The complementary probability then becomes

$$1 - {3n\choose k}^{-1}
\times
\left({3n\choose k} - 3{2n\choose k} + 3{n\choose k}\right)
\\ = {3n\choose k}^{-1}
\left( 3{2n\choose k} - 3{n\choose k} \right).$$

This confirms the two answers that were first to appear.