# Probability of rolling a die N times and having shown all the numbers .

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate the probability of rolling a die $N$ times and seeing all the values $1$ to $6$ in these $N$ trials at least once.

From this question, I am going to solve a more complex question that is:
I have $N$ nodes of $C$ clusters each of size $c_j$. I want to subsample the the data and choose $M$ nodes out of it, and I need the probability of having at least one sample from each cluster. In other words I want to subsample but with high probability have at least one member of each cluster in my subsampled set; so I need to measure that probability.

Thanks all.

Comment: Related: [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Thanks for pointing into coupon collector's problem. I am looking for something similar but without replacement and for each cluster we have $c_j$ members. or let's say we have $c_j$ instances of coupon $j$

Answer (score 2):

Using      the     technique      from     the      following     [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2172876/)  we have  for
the   probability  from   first  principles   (exponential  generating
functions and generalized Stirling numbers) that it is given by

$$\frac{1}{M!} {N\choose M}^{-1} \times
M! [z^M] \prod_{j=1}^C
\sum_{k=1}^{c_j} \frac{c_j!}{(c_j-k)!} \frac{z^k}{k!}
= {N\choose M}^{-1}
[z^M] \prod_{j=1}^C
\sum_{k=1}^{c_j} {c_j\choose k} z^k.$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{N\choose M}^{-1}
[z^M] \prod_{j=1}^C (-1+(1+z)^{c_j}).}$$

For the special case of all clusters having the same size $j$
we get

$${N\choose M}^{-1} [z^M] (-1+(1+z)^j)^C
= {N\choose M}^{-1} [z^M]
\sum_{q=0}^C {C\choose q} (-1)^{C-q} (1+z)^{qj}.$$

This is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{N\choose M}^{-1}
\sum_{q=0}^C {C\choose q} (-1)^{C-q} {qj\choose M}.}$$

We  can use  this to  compute  the expected  number of  draws until  a
representative  from  every cluster  has  been  seen.  Note  that  the
complementary  probability counts  draws where  at least  one type  of
cluster is missing, i.e. the number  of draws until having seen all is
more than $M.$ Hence we get for the expectation

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[T] = N-j+1
- \sum_{M=0}^{N-j} {N\choose M}^{-1}
\sum_{q=0}^C {C\choose q} (-1)^{C-q} {qj\choose M}.}$$

As a sanity check when $j=1$ the expectation should be $C.$
We obtain

$$C
- \sum_{M=0}^{C-1} {C\choose M}^{-1}
\sum_{q=M}^C {C\choose q} (-1)^{C-q} {q\choose M}.$$

Now we have

$${C\choose q} {q\choose M} =
\frac{C!}{(C-q)! \times M! \times (q-M)!}
= {C\choose M} {C-M\choose C-q}.$$

Substituting we find

$$C
- \sum_{M=0}^{C-1} {C\choose M}^{-1} {C\choose M}
\sum_{q=M}^C {C-M\choose C-q} (-1)^{C-q}
\\ = C
- \sum_{M=0}^{C-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{C-M} {C-M\choose C-M-q} (-1)^{C-M-q}
= C
- \sum_{M=0}^{C-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{C-M} {C-M\choose q} (-1)^{q}
\\ = C - \sum_{M=0}^{C-1} 0 = C,$$

as claimed. Here we have used that $C-1\ge M$ or $C\ge M+1\gt M$.

Comment: Thank, I will review the answer tonight, can you please take a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3119313/how-many-players-to-play-coupon-collector-without-replacement-so-they-collect-al