# Quantguide -- Repetitious Game II without replacement

Tags: probability, expected-value

Audrey repeatedly draws cards from a standard 52-card deck without replacement. Compute the expected number of draws for Audrey to get at least one card from each suit.

My answer is:
1+ (12/40 + 1) + (23.7/27 + 1) + ((23.7 - 23.7/27 + 12)/14 + 1) = 7.665079

where I simply assume every time after the draw of getting a unique suit, the rest of cards belonging to the un-drawn suits follow uniform distribution and evenly scatter around the drawn suit cards that remain in the deck. I am not sure if this approach is correct. I don't know if this is the correct approach for this kind of question.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is answered by this older post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2172876/177399 Both solutions there are somewhat difficult to find, I’m not sure if Quantguide had a simpler method in mind.